# How to pass value from a component to another component file which is inside a library without Parent-Child relation?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-components

I have a library "user-form" which has component and html files.

HTML File `"user-form.component.html"`:

```
 <div class="relative-pos">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchParam"
    (ngModelChange)="search()" />

  <div class="autocomplete-custom-dropdown" *ngIf="canDisplay()">
   
    <div class="table-head-fixed table-common">
      <div class="tbl-header">
        <table cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" Border="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-header" *ngFor="let mainHead of suggestedResponse?.headers">
                {{mainHead}}
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="common-scroll">
        <div class="tbl-content height-dropdown-main" malihu-scrollbar>
          <table cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" Border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let dt of suggestedResponse?.data" (click)="selectedVal(dt)">
                <td *ngFor = "let d of dt['code']">{{d}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

This HTML file is loaded as a part of library in company-form(another html) file like this.

"`company-form.component.html`"

```
<user-form  [request]="getDestinationNumberRequest()" ></user-form>
```

The 1st html(user-form.component.html") gets loaded as a part of "company-form.component.html" and after that when I open a modal (also in company-form.component.html), onclick of a button I have to set the value in one of the input box of already loaded page behind it.
But the problem is in **company-form.component.html** I have the library tag and not the actual input tag so I can't use
`[(ngModel)]`
The actual input box is in html of library which already has the ngModel

```
<button (click) ="setDestinationNameCode()"></button>
```

and I also have tried using `@Output` using even emitter on button click but nothing happened.
Here is what I tried.

1. Declare @Output

`@Output() setDestCode = new EventEmitter<String>();`

2. Call it in setDestinationNameCode()

`this.setDestCode.emit(code);`

3. set that in
   `<user-form  [request]="getDestinationNumberRequest()" (setDestCode)="getData($event)" ></user-form>`
4. And call `getData($event)` in `company-form.component.ts` to use the data and set it in `searchParam` because the `ngModdel` for that is already defined.

But nothing happens.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using service and variable data should be a subject.
for example (That is not a full code,It is an idea so you can use and work on it) -

```
export class SubjectService {

  private somedata = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }

  updateData() {
    this.somedata.next({ text: "Test Data" });
  }

  getData() {
    return this.somedata.asObservable();
  }
}
```

You can subscribe it to your components like this

```
data: Subscription;

you need to unsubscribe it ngOnDestroy method
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea but it was way too short to understand.
I didn't understand anything as to what to do exactly.
Can you please be more specific and a bit more detailed ?

Comment: Check this part  "Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service" in 
 this tutorial https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: I already saw that article, all examples are for simple input box, not library ones.
If you have a clear answer or guidance then do reply or else sharing links isn't recommended